# Fixing error message that results instead of a line plot

Tags: plotting, bugs

I am trying to run the function to perform a plot but instead, I am getting the error:

[image]

```
Message[With::lvset, {dt = 0.01, tfinal = 100., \[Gamma] = 1, k = 1, 
  Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] = 1, Subscript[\[Sigma], 2] = 2}, 
 Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] = 1, Subscript[\[Sigma], 1]]
```

The function, which is a for loop that stores the values in a list and plots them is :

```
With[{dt = 0.01, tfinal = 100.0, \[Gamma] = 1, k = 1, 
  Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] = 1, Subscript[\[Sigma], 2] = 2},
 x = {0, 0};
 a = 0.0;
 alist = {};
 dtsqrt = Sqrt[dt];
 M = ( {
    {1 + 1, -1},
    {-1, 1 + 1}
   } );
 \[Sigma] = ( {
    {1, 0},
    {0, 2}
   } );
 Do[
  dx = -M.x*dt + 
    dtsqrt*\[Sigma]. RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 2];
  a += x[[1]] dx[[2]] - x[[2]] dx[[1]] ;
  x += dx;
  AppendTo[alist, {t, a}], {t, dt, tfinal, dt}];
 p1 = ListPlot[alist, Joined -> True];
 Show[p1]
 ]
```

Could you tell me where the error emerges from or perhaps how to stop it from occurring?

Comment: The error message is trying to tell you that you cannot have `Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] = 1` or `Subscript[\[Sigma], 2] = 2` as part of the specification of `With`. Subscripts don't always behave how you might expect them to, so it's better to avoid them until you learn more about when they work and when they don't. There are some good posts on this site about possible workarounds if you really need to have a subscript. If you don't absolutely require a subscript, I would use `\[Sigma]1 = 1` and `\[Sigma]2 = 2`.

Comment: Thank you  It worked

Comment: You can use `Format[σ1] = Subscript[σ, 1]` to have `σ1` display as a `Subscript` in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Subscript to name your variables. Name them $a1$ and $a2$ for example. This would solve the problem.

Comment: Why would this be the case?

Comment: Subscripted variables are not symbols, which is what your error msg is telling you.  The `Notation` package can transform subscripted variables to symbols, but you had better know what you are doing before using that pkg.  It is generally best not to use subscripts unless absolutely necessary.